# My ruby-on-rails guide test project is giving me a error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have been trying to follow the [Getting Started Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) for Ruby on Rails and it is giving me an error when running `bundle install`

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/ext/bootsnap C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r ./siteconf20220314-9264-an0w4o.rb extconf.rb creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/ext/bootsnap make DESTDIR\= clean

current directory: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/ext/bootsnap make DESTDIR\= generating bootsnap-x64-mingw-ucrt.def compiling bootsnap.c make: gcc: No such file or directory make: *** [Makefile:246: bootsnap.o] Erro 127

make failed, exit code 2
```

I have been trying to solve this problem with everything i got, searching here in stackoverflow, searching some solutions on github, and reinstalling the rails, even the ruby... tried to use other gems with the same functions but all gives the same error.

and when i try to use the solution that the terminal gives me (which is gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.4.2), another error appears

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Ext::BuildError)  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

 current directory: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3 C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r ./siteconf20220314-16176-wojw9e.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:498:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:591:in `try_link0'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:609:in `try_link'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:711:in `try_ldflags'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1895:in `pkg_config'
        from extconf.rb:35:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.1.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You have to install development tools in order to compile gems. On Windows, one option to get those is to install a Ruby+Devkit bundle from https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Comment: (Also, when posting code or error messages, please do not paste them as quotations but as code to retain the original line breaks. Your quoted messages are currently unreadable...)

Comment: The whole point of using SQLite as a default is that its supposed to be easy to setup or is preinstalled on many linux distros. If you're gonna torture yourself with developing on windows then just install Postgres instead which has a GUI installer and which is a database that you can actually use for deploying real applications. But I would just install Ubuntu or whatever flavor of Linux you prefer via WSL2 instead as almost all tutorials assume you're using Linux/OS-X and Windows compatiblity has never really been that big of a priority in the Ruby world.